# Couldn't click on a link that opens a menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to click on a link after the text "action". The HTML is:

```
<div _ngcontent-c10="" class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 20px;">
  <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="card" style="width:100% !important">
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="headerText">FLOATS &amp; MOVE</div>
     <hr _ngcontent-c10="">
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="text1">action</div>
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="text2">
        <a _ngcontent-c10="" class="waves-light" data-toggle="modal" mdbwaveseffect="" style="margin-right: -25%;" type="button">
          <img _ngcontent-c10="" src="assets/co-assets/icon-down-arrow-med.png">
        </a>
     </div>
     <div _ngcontent-c10=""class="text1">from</div>
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="text2"> 
        <a _ngcontent-c10="" class="waves-light" data-toggle="modal" mdbwaveseffect="" 
style="margin-right: -25%;" type="button">
           <img _ngcontent-c10="" src="assets/co-assets/icon-down-arrow-med.png"> 
        </a>
     </div>
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="text1">to</div>
     <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="text2">
        <a _ngcontent-c10="" class="waves-light" data-toggle="modal" mdbwaveseffect="" style="margin-right: -25%;" type="button">
           <img _ngcontent-c10="" src="assets/co-assets/icon-down-arrow-med.png">
        </a>
     </div>
```

The XPath I've used is:

```
//div[./text()='action']/following-sibling::div[1]/a
```

I've waited explicitly for 20 seconds with the condition `ElementToBeClickable` as follows:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(actionDropDown));
```

The interesting thing is I'm not getting `TimeOutException`.

Comment: Is this on a public website? Do you have control over the source code? Also I would recommend against using xpath selectors as they are clunky. I would break your xpath up into segements and add a sequence of waits to see what is causing the timeout e.g. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("//div[./text()='action']"));` then `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("//div[./text()='action']/following-sibling::div[1]"));` etc so that you get incrementally more specific with your selector. If you use a CSS selector it would be `div[text="action"] + div > a`.

Comment: do you prefer CSS to XPath? CSS selector is better?

Comment: I prefer CSS to Xpath. Depending on the use case depends on which you should use. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Webdriver unable to click on the element.Try the following options to click.

Use Action class

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text1'][contains(.,'action')]/following-sibling::div[1]/a"));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(ele).click().build().perform();
```

---

Use Javascripts executor

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text1'][contains(.,'action')]/following-sibling::div[1]/a"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: I couldn't click on the link after the text "from". Tried the XPaths `//div[@class='text1'][./text()='action']/following-sibling::div[3]/a` and `//div[@class='text1'][contains(.,'from')]/following-sibling::div[1]/a`

Comment: I'm not getting `TimeOutException` even though I've implemented explicit wait on the element.

Comment: Could you please look into this? I'm still cannot locate the element.